$a_k$ = $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\sin k}{k}} \frac{\sin t}{t} \,dx $ series convergence
Does this series converge: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k,\quad \text{where} \quad a_k= \int_{0}^{\frac{\sin k}{k}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \,dx ?$$

Please do some of the following steps: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question. I can give you an answer once you've stated some things you know, have tried, think are relevant, etc.

I have to ask, did you even bother trying anything? You know what constitutes a good question on here by now [tour]  -1 and Vote-To-Close

@Mike If you have to ask me this question, you also have to check my other questions. I am always writing some of my results if I find any of them interesting. In this question I tried ratio test, Cauchy's test, tried to use Taylor series, tried to majorate this series with $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ (does not work though, because it can be less than zero). Nothing worked. So, what's the point in writing it?

Yes it does. Because $a_k = b_k -c_k$, where
$$
b_k = \frac{\sin k}k,\quad c_k = \int_0^{\frac{\sin k}k} \left(1-\frac{\sin x}x\right)dx,
$$
and series $\sum_k b_k$, $\sum_k c_k$ are convergent.

I understand  why $b_k$ converges, but it is unclear to me what to do with $c_k$.

There is A such that $Ax^2 > 1-\sin x/x > 0$ and integral is majorated $|\int\ldots dx|< B|\sin k/k|^3$. $1/k^3$ series converges, hence $|c_k|$ converges.

Actually, when $x\geq0$, we have $0\leq x-\sin x\leq\frac{x^3}6$, so $$|c_k|= \int_0^{\frac{|\sin k|}k} \left(1-\frac{\sin x}x\right)dx\leq\int_0^{\frac{|\sin k|}k} \frac{x^2}6dx=\frac{|\sin^3k|}{18k^3}<\frac{1}{18k^3}.$$

I am curious to know what could be the asymptotic  of  $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }
\text{Si}\left(\frac{\sin   (k)}{k}\right)$$
